# Controlar inicio de sesion en varias pestañas

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar

estoy trabajando en un proyecto con vue js en quasar y quisiera saber como puedo controlar el inicio de sesión en varias pestañas, es decir, necesito que cuando un usuario abra otra pestaña no pueda iniciar sesión en esa nueva pestaña, como podría hacer eso? existe alguna librería? me mencionaron en algún momento utilizar SocketIO pero la verdad desconozco como puedo hacer esto. Sé que netflix utiliza una función parecida para controlar el inicio de sesión en distintas pestañas.

Comment: Has intentado algo??

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [mcve]